# Counter of entered characters for Vaadin Text Field (Without JS)

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to add counter inside Vaadin Text Field's helper text:

[image]

Entered characters / Maximum possible number of characters

**Question**:
How can I get the current number of characters entered by the user, without using JS?

Comment: Which vaadin version are you using? For v8 there exists such an addon

Comment: I am using v14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the value change mode of the text field to `ValueChangeMode.EAGER`, then there will be a server-side value change event every time the value is changed which means that you can do `getValue().length()` to find the length. This approach is really straightforward but it has the drawback that it causes some redundant network traffic since each change needs to be processed on the server.

If you want something that avoids sending all changes to the server, then a little bit of JavaScript would be needed, unless you can find an existing add-on that already integrates that JavaScript for you.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful. 